# high-availability nodes for streaming data are disconnected

Tags: streaming, high-availability, dolphindb

underversion 1.30.7 of dolphindb , the node is disconnected and can be manually activated after the high-availability flow data table is created,  what is the reason for the unsuccessful creation of the table?

```py
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Core was generated by `./dolphindb -home /root/dolphindb/server/data/P3-NODE1 -logFile/root/dolphindb'.

Program terminated with signal 11 , Segmentation fault.

#0 0x00000000008da027 in RealtimeTable::getKeyColumnIndex(int) const () Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64 (gdb) bt

#0 0x00000000008da027 in RealtimeTable::getKeyC olumnIndex(int) const ()

#1 0x00000000007039b3 in RegisterLogEntry::setTable(SmartPointer<Table> const&) ()

#2 0x000000000070853b in StreamingHA::registerDataFile(std::string const&, SmartPointer< StreamingDataFile> const&, bool) ()

#3 0x0000000000711a9c in StreamingHAManagerImpl::registerStreamTable(int, std::string const&, SmartPointer<Table> const&) ()

#4 0x00000000007ae416 in OperatorImp::haStreamTableInternal(Heap*, std::vector< SmartPointer<Constant>, std::allocator<SmartPointer<Constant>> >&) ()

# 5 0x00000000007aedbf in OperatorImp :: haStreamTable(Heap*, std::vector<SmartPointer<Constant>, std::allocator<SmartPointer<Constant>> >&) ()

#6 0x00007fb64c31877e in SystemFunction::call(Heap*, std::vector<SmartPointer <Constant >, std::allocator<SmartPoin ter<Constant>> >&)() from ./libDolphinDB.so

#7 0x00000000006d9a96 in SessionImp::run(SmartPointer<FunctionDef> const&, std::vector<SmartPointer<Constant> , std ::allocator<SmartPointer<Constant>> >&) ()

#8 0x00000000006deeb8 in SessionImp::run(std:: string const&, std::vector<SmartPointer<Constant>, std::allocator<SmartPointer<Constant> >> &) ()

#9 0x00000000005e5415 in APISocketConsole::execute() ()

#10 0x00000000005e1491 in SocketConsole::run() ()

#11 0x000000000062989e in Worker::run() ()

#12 0x00 007fb64be6b6dc in Runnable:: start() () from ./libDolphinDB.so

#13 0x00007fb64be6c8a0 in Thread::startFunc(void*) () from ./libDolphinDB.so

#14 0x00007fb64b1f5dd5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

#15 0x00007e ina2 () fro m /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: It is recommended to use the latest version of dolphindb to create a high-availability flow data table.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest release of DolphinDB (V1.30.18/V2.00.6), the mentioned issues have been fixed. Upgrade your server and have a try.

The following script creates a high-availability stream table “haDevSt“ in the raft group “2“ where *cacheLimit* is 100000 and *keyColumn* is “id“.

> t1=table(1:0,
> ["id","source_address","source_port","destination_address","destination_port"],
> [STRING,INT,INT,INT,INT] ) haStreamTable(2,t1,"haDevSt",100000,"id")

To drop a high-availability stream table, call *dropStreamTable(tableName)*.

For more information, please check the https://dolphindb.com/help/index.html